# Deviceready event doesn't fire with phoneGap in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, events, cordova

I'm using mac os lion with the latest xcode version.
I installed phonegap from the official website (the 1.2.0 version), I saw the welcome message "phonegap is working".
But I want to write files with the phoneGap API on the iOs simulator (version 4.3) and when I try to fire the "deviceready" event it doesn't works at all.

Here is my code in 'index.html' :

```
<srcipt type='text/javascript'>
function fun(){
 alert("fired");
}
document.addEventListener("deviceready", fun, false);
</script>
```

I can't see the alert. I really don't know what it doesn't works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine for me in a new PhoneGap project (although I had to change <**srcipt** type='text/javascript'> to <**script** type='text/javascript'>

Could this typo have caused your issue?

I added your code above (with the typo edited) to the `<head>` of the index.html page and upon running the project it popped up the expected alert.

Comment: In fact I was including the file "phonegap.js" in version 0.9x and not the good one "phonegap.js" in version 1.2 . But thanks for answering me ;)

Comment: Ahhh... that old chestnut. Yeah, it is good to create a new project and copy your assets in from the old project when upgrading.

Answer (score 6):

I met your problem, too. I think that you may copy the files under the "www" folder in Android project to iOS project. I did the same thing, and all phonegap APIs and the "deviceready" event didn't work. I guess that the phonegap.js in the two platform are different. Therefore, I create a new phoneGap project in xcode and copy the generated phonegap.js to the working project. It works!

Comment: Thank you for this glaringly obvious fact that I was completely missing!